# Creating RDD of words and their index in the original text

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, string-parsing

I want to process a large text using spark and the order of the words in the text is important and should be kept.

I tried the following approach but it was not successful for large texts. It has out of memory issue.(obviously!)

```
hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "$$$$$");//read whole text

JavaRDD<String> texts = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(inputFile, TextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, hadoopConf).values().map((x) -> x.toString());
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> lines = texts.flatMap(new readDocuments());


public class readDocuments implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String,  Integer>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // line , index in original text
    @Override
    public Iterator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> call(String text) throws Exception {
        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> lines = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Integer>>();
        String[] tempLines = text.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tempLines.length; i++) {
            if (tempLines[i].length() > 0)
                lines.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(tempLines[i], i));
        }
        return lines.iterator();
    }
}
```

I also tried to read files using `sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(inputFile)` but the same problem!

Any idea or hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks good in your code. I think you need to tune the job memory parameters. Can you please add error stacktrace, spark-submit memory configuration parameters and node configuration?

Comment: @squid The problem is it doesn't run on several cores. During the process of 'flatmap' to create 'lines', it only uses one core, even the others are free!

Comment: `sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(....).repartition(xyz).values().map(..)` replace xyz with int value, which calculates based on input size. xyz= (total input size in MB /64)

Comment: How can I keep the order of text in this way? If I use partition method during the reading text file, it distribute the text to several partitions and no garanty to have the correct order of the text. @squid

Comment: try `zipWithIndex` to add line number then repartition RDD, later use index number to get the order.